# Render JSON without replacing characters in Jinja

Tags: python, json, flask, jinja2

I have some Python data that will be sent to a JavaScript chart.  I dump it to JSON and pass it to the template.  When I render the data, it contains html entities (`&#34;`) instead of quotes, which isn't valid.  How do I correctly pass the JSON data from Python to JavaScript?

```
pieData = [{'color': '#400068', 'name': 'xyz', 'value': 10}, {'color': '#4a8624', 'name': 'abc', 'value': 30}]
render_template('index.html', piedata=json.dumps(pieData))
```

```javascript
var pieData2 = {{ piedata }};
// renders as
var pieData2 = [{&#34;color&#34;: &#34;#5461ae&#34;, &#34;name&#34;: &#34;fizi.yadav&#34;, &#34;value&#34;: 10}, {&#34;color&#34;: &#34;#e1dce4&#34;, &#34;name&#34;: &#34;surya.pradhan&#34;, &#34;value&#34;: 30}, {&#34;color&#34;: &#34;#7835f0&#34;, &#34;name&#34;: &#34;fred.hsu&#34;, &#34;value&#34;: 276}]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Jinja autoescapes potentially unsafe characters (such as quotes) to avoid security issues.  You need to tell it that the data you are rendering is safe, either by using the `|safe` filter in the template or wrapping it in `Markup` in the view.  You can also use the `|tojson` filter rather than parsing and marking the JSON manually.

Use `Markup` to mark it safe from the view.

```
from markupsafe import Markup
render_template('index.html', piedata=Markup(json.dumps(pieData)))
```

Or mark it safe in the template.

```html
{{ piedata|safe }}
```

Preferably, just convert it in the template without calling `json.dumps` in the view.  Older versions of Flask required calling `|tojson|safe`, but the `|safe` is no longer needed.

```html
{{ piedata|tojson }}
```